# Textarea carriage return not working in textarea with preventDefault()

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, razor, textarea

I want to type a few characters and press return to a new line, then save it and redisplay when other actions happen.
ex.

> Sentence 1
>   Sentence 2
>   ...

But I have a snippet of jquery that stops my form from submitting but it also stops the carriage return in the textarea. How can I still allow carriage returns in my textarea but still stop the form from submitting?

```js
$(document).keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
```

Here is my razor code and rendered html.

```html
<textarea class="form-control input-lg valid" cols="20" data-val="true" data-val-maxlength="Max length is 250" data-val-maxlength-max="250" id="inspirationsId" name="Inspirations" rows="2" style="min-height: 64px; margin-top: 10px; max-width: 500px; max-height: 460px; height: 62px; margin-bottom: 0px;" aria-invalid="false" aria-describedby="inspirationsId-error">I like trees!</textarea>
```

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Inspirations, new { @id = "inspirationsId", @class = "form-control inspirationsHideDontTakeUpSpace input-lg", @style = "min-height: 64px; margin-top: 10px; max-width: 500px; max-height: 460px;" })
```

Comment: Pressing enter in a textarea will add a new line (and just click on the _Run Code Snippet_ above to prove it)

Comment: oh ya you're right, I have a jquery keypress event that checks for key 13 and if true I do a e.preventDefault to prevent my form from submitting, It looks like its preventing any carriage return how can I change this to still allow carriage returns?

Comment: Edit you question to explain the actual issue and include the javascript :)

Comment: I think if I just remove the e.preventDefault() I'll be fine.

Comment: If you don't edit your question so that it can be answered, you may as well delete it.

Comment: You can always check the target - e.g. `if(e.target.tagName == 'TEXTAREA') { return; } elseif (e.which == 13) { e.preventDefault(); }` (not tested yet but should work)